# How to Copy Contents in one DataGridview to another DataGridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I want to copy from one datagridview to another datagridview.

I tried the code below but I still have all data in the first columns :

```
For c = 0 To ReadDataDataGridView.Rows.Count - 1
    For t = 0 To ReadDataDataGridView.Columns.Count - 1
        DataGridView1.Rows.Add(ReadDataDataGridView.Rows(c).Cells(t).Value)
    Next
Next
```

Comment: Is the DGV bound to a data source?

Comment: You can use the merge function explained here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk68ew7b(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that you're adding a new row for each and every cell in `ReadDataDataGridView`. You need to create only *one* row in each row iteration. As of now, you're creating `n` rows in each row iteration (where `n` is the number of columns).

Here's one way to do it:

**VB.NET**

```vb
'References to source and target grid.

Dim sourceGrid As DataGridView = Me.DataGridView1
Dim targetGrid As DataGridView = Me.DataGridView2

'Copy all rows and cells.

Dim targetRows = New List(Of DataGridViewRow)

For Each sourceRow As DataGridViewRow In sourceGrid.Rows

    If (Not sourceRow.IsNewRow) Then

        Dim targetRow = CType(sourceRow.Clone(), DataGridViewRow)

        'The Clone method do not copy the cell values so we must do this manually.
        'See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.clone(v=vs.110).aspx

        For Each cell As DataGridViewCell In sourceRow.Cells
            targetRow.Cells(cell.ColumnIndex).Value = cell.Value
        Next

        targetRows.Add(targetRow)

    End If

Next

'Clear target columns and then clone all source columns.

targetGrid.Columns.Clear()

For Each column As DataGridViewColumn In sourceGrid.Columns
    targetGrid.Columns.Add(CType(column.Clone(), DataGridViewColumn))
Next

'It's recommended to use the AddRange method (if available)
'when adding multiple items to a collection.

targetGrid.Rows.AddRange(targetRows.ToArray())
```

**C#**

```cs
//References to source and target grid.

DataGridView sourceGrid = this.dataGridView1;
DataGridView targetGrid = this.dataGridView2;

//Copy all rows and cells.

var targetRows = new List<DataGridViewRow>();

foreach (DataGridViewRow sourceRow in sourceGrid.Rows)
{

    if (!sourceRow.IsNewRow)
    {

        var targetRow = (DataGridViewRow)sourceRow.Clone();

        //The Clone method do not copy the cell values so we must do this manually.
        //See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.clone(v=vs.110).aspx

        foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in sourceRow.Cells)
        {
            targetRow.Cells[cell.ColumnIndex].Value = cell.Value;
        }

        targetRows.Add(targetRow);

    }

}

//Clear target columns and then clone all source columns.

targetGrid.Columns.Clear();

foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in sourceGrid.Columns)
{
    targetGrid.Columns.Add((DataGridViewColumn)column.Clone());
}

//It's recommended to use the AddRange method (if available)
//when adding multiple items to a collection.

targetGrid.Rows.AddRange(targetRows.ToArray());
```

Comment: I use this code but it error that " No row can be added to a DataGridView control that does not have columns. Columns must be added first."

Comment: @Thanapipat You need to clone the columns if the schema of your target grid doesn't match that of the source grid. I've updated my answer to give you an example.

Comment: To clarify an issue: the reason why Bjørn-Roger uses the line `If (Not sourceRow.IsNewRow) Then` is a datagridview will create a newrow automatically as soon as columns are added to it. You will end up with a row count one more than you might expect. I believe if you set this parameter before you add columns to your targetGrid you can avoid this: `targetGrid.AllowUserToAddRows = False`

Answer (score 0):

As much as I remember you just need to put this in your code

```
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In classDataGridView.SelectedRows
        Dim text As String
        For Each cell As DataGridViewCell In classDataGridView.SelectedCells
            text = cell.Value.ToString
            For Each scheduleCell As DataGridViewCell In scheduleDataGridView.SelectedCells
                scheduleCell.Value.ToString.Equals(text)
            Next scheduleCell
        Next cell
    Next
```

Comment: i need copy one by one because after i want modified this data.

Comment: @Roman you can modify that data from datasource and than call that datasource as Mgolwrote you

Comment: do you want to copy selected cells or all cells?

Comment: @Roman If my answer solved your problem, please click the big checkbox to accept it as the answer. This way, other people know that the problem is solved. As a bonus you'll receive some rep-points and a badge;)

Answer (score 0):

I Hope this work for your project.

```
DataGridView1.Columns.Clear()
            For Each Col As DataGridViewColumn In DataGridView2.Columns
                DataGridView1.Columns.Add(DirectCast(Col.Clone, DataGridViewColumn))
            Next
            For rowIndex As Integer = 0 To (DataGridView2.Rows.Count - 1)
                DataGridView1.Rows.Add(DataGridView2.Rows(rowIndex).Cells.Cast(Of DataGridViewCell).Select(Function(c) c.Value).ToArray)
            Next
```