# how to copy datagridview1 data to another datagridview?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I am working with visual basic 6.0 for school project , I want copy datagridview of form1 and paste it on datagridview of form2.
when form2 load at that time all data show in datagridview.
i use below code but it show only first row

```
DataGridView1.Columns.Clear()
        For Each Col As DataGridViewColumn In View_Staff.DataGridView1.Columns
            DataGridView1.Columns.Add(DirectCast(Col.Clone, DataGridViewColumn))
        Next
  DataGridView1.Rows.Add(View_Staff.DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells.Cast(Of DataGridViewCell).Select(Function(c) c.Value).ToArray)
```

Comment: Let's see your code and we'll help you figure out where you've gone wrong.

Comment: I use 0 index so that it show only first row ...how would I show all rows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the first thing you'll need to do is get rid of all of your code, since it doesn't run in VB 6.0.  There isn't any DataGridView in VB 6.0, there isn't any DirectCast operator in VB 6.0.

Alternatively, if your school project is really in VB.Net, then two minutes of googling will reveal that this question has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25461139/how-to-copy-contents-in-one-datagridview-to-another-datagridview).