# vb.net Datagrid Value to another datagrid

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

Hello guys I have a problem on datagrid value pass to another datagrid using vb.net.because most tutorials on youtube had fix values on rows in datagrid.i want the one the was fetched on database then pass it to Datagrid1 then to Datagrid 2 when button click.thank you so much

the code on the form load goes like this:

```
    Me.DataGridView1.columns.Add("1","1")

Me.DataGridView1.columns.Add("2","1")
Me.DataGridView1.columns.Add("3","3")
Me.DataGridView2.columns.Add("1","1")
Me.DataGridView2.columns.Add("2","1")
```

and on the button for passing value:

```
dim dr as  new System.Windows.Forms.datagridviewrow 
for each dr In me.datagridview1.selectedRows
  Me.DatagridView2.rows.Add(dr.cells(0).value,dr.cells(1).value,dr.cells(2).value....and so on)
```

Comment: What have you tried? Post the code formatted as code with the edit link below your question.

Comment: Like what? There is no this.

Comment: Check [How to Copy Contents in one DataGridview to another DataGridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25461139/how-to-copy-contents-in-one-datagridview-to-another-datagridview)

Comment: Do not post code in a comment. Edit your question and add the formatted code there.

Comment: ive tried the codes on the link you give..thanks...BUT it copies everything into the datagrid2..i like the one that it only transfers the row you have selecte

Comment: Then change `Rows` to `SelectedRows` in `For Each sourceRow As DataGridViewRow In sourceGrid.SelectedRows ...`

Answer (score 0):

```
    Dim sourceGrid As DataGridView = Me.DataGridView1
    Dim targetGrid As DataGridView = Me.DataGridView2
    Dim targetRows = New List(Of DataGridViewRow)
    For Each sourceRow As DataGridViewRow In sourceGrid.Rows
        If (Not sourceRow.IsNewRow) Then
            Dim targetRow = CType(sourceRow.Clone(), DataGridViewRow)
            For Each cell As DataGridViewCell In sourceRow.Cells
                targetRow.Cells(cell.ColumnIndex).Value = cell.Value
            Next
            targetRows.Add(targetRow)
        End If
    Next
    targetGrid.Columns.Clear()
    For Each column As DataGridViewColumn In sourceGrid.Columns
        targetGrid.Columns.Add(CType(column.Clone(), DataGridViewColumn))
    Next
    targetGrid.Rows.AddRange(targetRows.ToArray())
```